# How do I use link_to in a relative manner in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using omniauth-facebook gem to do some Facebook login stuff. The call works in such a way that when /auth/facebook is called, it does the authentication process. All of that works fine when I manually enter the URL: `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook`

However, when I took my code only, my domain is setup such that my apps have URLs such as:

```
http://railsapps.mydomain.com/app1  
http://railsapps.mydomain.com/app2  
http://railsapps.mydomain.com/app3
```

etc.

Now in my index page I have a link that is written in my .html.erb file as such:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
```

When I run this locally and click on the link it correctly goes to localhost:3000/auth/facebook and everything is good in the world. However, when I go online with this same code and click on this link it goes to: `http://railsapps.mydomain.com/auth/facebook` (which of course doesn't work, since it should be going to `railsapps.mydomain.com/app1/auth/facebook`.

Any help that could be provided in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", root_url + "auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
```

or if that doesn't work try request.host:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "http://#{request.host}/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your `default_url_options` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options
  if Rails.env.production?
    {:host => "railsapps.mydomain.com/app1"}
  else  
    {}
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried this, but no luck. Same problem persists. Besides, my Rails environment on my domain is set to Development, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: ah ok, use simply: `def default_url_options; {:host => "railsapps.mydomain.com/app1"}; end` then

Comment: why do you have your server in dev mode online?

Comment: I have my reasons for having it in dev mode online, this was not the point of this topic.

Comment: Of course, yet you're using a damn hack to fit your needs, where default_url_options makes things easy no matter the environment. Your choice.

Comment: actually it's really weird your `root_url`is fine if you haven't set the default_url_options properly.